# unable to edit excel worksheet in browser

Tags: 2013, excel, office-web-apps, licensing, edit

We have installed SharePoint 2013 and Office web apps 2013, linked with SharePoint.

Now we are unable to utilize the option "Edit in browser".

We are getting below error.

> Excel webapp
>
> Sorry you don't have a license to edit documents with
>   Excel web apps. Please get in touch with your helpdesk.

We have a license of Office web apps.

We don't have any internet connection to our servers, only an Intranet.

We want our users to edit the Excel file at a same time in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Encountered same issue when setting up one of my lab farms in Azure a while back.

When setting up the Office Web Apps working with SharePoint farm, there's a step during configuration that you need to perform logged on to one of the OWA farm machines:

```
$owaFarm = Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm;
$owaFarm .OpenFromUrlEnabled = $true;
```

After that the error should stop and Excel documents should render in browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this `Powershell` command on your OWA server

```
Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm
```

and check if `EditingEnabled` property is set to true.